# jQuery UI autocomplete display if no results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working with jQuery UI autocomplete plugin and want to display some text if no results are found. I have seen a lot of examples to do this with remote datasets, but I have the source set to a local JSON array. Here is the code I am working with right now, it hides all rows that do not match the selected value. I want to hide all rows and display a 'no entries found' in the text box when a user is typing text that does not match any of the available tags

```
$( "#archiveVendor" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui){
        var emptyRow = '<tr class="emptyArchive"><td class="approved_content">---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td class="payment_status">---</td></tr>';
        $('.archive_inner .emptyArchive').remove();
        $('.archive_inner tr').show().filter(function(index){
            var tds = $(this).children('td');
            if($(tds).length == 4){
                if($(tds[1]).text() == '---'){
                    return false;
                }
                var title = $(tds[0]).attr('title');
                return title === ui.item.value ? false : true;
            }
        }).hide();

        if($('.archive_approved tr:visible').length == 1){
            $('.archive_approved tbody').append(emptyRow);
        }
        if($('.archive_denied tr:visible').length == 1){
            $('.archive_denied tbody').append(emptyRow);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Display it where, in the empty dropdown? Wouldn't the user then be able to select it?

Comment: that's the issue, i don't want the user to select it, just display the text in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can compare the ui.item.value with the array?

```
if(jQuery.inArray(ui.item.value, json_array) == -1) { add text to right field and hide() other fields }
```